# fix and save split widths

Tags: vim, layout, save

I was wondering how one can store split widths at a fix widths in vim.
I'm would like to use a layout like:
`N` = NERDTree
`F1` = Source file space
`S` = bash in `ConqueTerm`
`CW` = cscope result list window

```
|   | F1       |   |
|   |          |   |
| N |          | S |
|   |--------------|
|   |     CW       |
```

where I would like to have N, S and CW fixed and files that can be opened in the area F1 without moving the width of `S`, `N` seems to be fixed so I assume it should be possible to fix `S` as well. Right now, it keeps vchangin it's widths when I go to NerdTree and open another file into my `F1` space by hittinfg `s` for example. And I'm constantly resizing my splits to have space allocated reasonably.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to turn Vim into a GUI. Sisyphean task, IMO. In this and many other things, it would be better to adapt to Vim, rather than strive to adapt Vim to yourself. Vim works very well when you let temporary windows be temporary. However... see [How to save window, split, and buffer layout?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-to-save-window-split-and-buffer-layout)

Comment: @Amadan yes, I agree with what you are saying "it would be better to adapt to Vim" but only partially and due to the flexibility vim offers, I was wondering if the above explained is achievable. Thanks for the link in any case. I'll go see how that will help my goal!